# 401 Unauthorized error on subsequent REST API requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am getting **401 Unauthorized** error on **subsequent REST API requests**, after the 1st successful response with 200 Ok. See steps to reproduce below.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Authenticate and Get Authorization Token - Successful
   [image]
2. Submit First API Request - Successful

[image]

3. Submit Subsequent API Request - **401 Unauthorized**

[image]

**Note**: This works fine when I debug locally or deploy on Azure. However, **I get 401 Unauthorized in one of my hosting environment**. And support staff giving hard time and not able to resolve this issue.

**Note**: You may see different bearer token in my screenshots but I am passing same token in all requests.

- Why is it giving issues only on 1 hosting environment and on subsequent requests?
- Do I need any specific changes to my web.config file so my subsequent requests are recognized by same bearer token?

**Update-1**:
Below is the response from both my domain (401) and azure (200 ok) put in side-by-side. I see Azure additionally sends ARRAffinity and ARRAffinitySameSite in cookies. Hope this info might help.

[image]

Comment: What could be happening, is the server goes to sleep (have seen this happening alot on IIS that by default is 20 minutes), if no request happens during x time, it will go to sleep and the token is lost

Try to see the Azure configurations

Comment: How long does it take for exception to occur?  If 30 seconds it is looking for a proxy and setting proxy to null will fix : request.Proxy = null;

Comment: Thanks Camadas and jdweng for your responses. 
As soon as I get the token, I submit other requests to server within few seconds so surely the time is not expired or server cant sleep so soon, then only first one gets me the result and others 401 unauthorized. 
I guess it doesn't recognize the token from 2nd request onward. I will check azure config and try setting request.Proxy = null (btw, where do I set this?)

Comment: Just figured it out, I was missing machine key in my web.config file needed for web farm as my hosting environment uses 3 nameservers.

From MS Docs: If you deploy application in a Web farm, you must ensure that the configuration files on each server share the same value for validationKey and decryptionKey, which are used for hashing and decryption respectively. This is required as you cant guarantee which server will handle successive requests
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649308(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing **Machine Key** in my web.config file needed for web farm as my hosting environment uses 3 nameservers, as it didn't recognize the token from 2nd request onward.

From MS Docs: If you deploy application in a Web farm, you must ensure that the configuration files on each server share the same value for validationKey and decryptionKey for **Machine Key**, which are used for hashing and decryption respectively. This is required as you cant guarantee which server will handle successive requests.

[MS Docs: Webfarm Deployment Considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649308(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations)